# I have to write a program that outputs the largest X number, given X number and a huge filesize

Tags: ruby, sorting, numbers, readfile, large-files

So far, I have this code that reads a file and sorts it using Ruby. But this doesn't sort the numbers correctly and I think it will be  inefficient, given that the file can be as big as 200GB and contains a number on each line. Can you suggest what else to do?

```
File.open("topN.txt", "w") do |file|
  File.readlines("N.txt").sort.reverse.each do |line|
    file.write(line.chomp<<"\n")
  end
End
```

After everyone help over here this is how my code is looking so far...

> ```
> begin
>
>   puts "What is the file name?"
>   file = gets.chomp
>
>   puts "Whats is the N number?"
>   myN = Integer(gets.chomp)
>
> rescue ArgumentError
>
>   puts "That's not a number, try again"
>   retry
> end
>
> topN = File.open(file).each_line.max(myN){|a,b| a.to_i <=> b.to_i}
> puts topN
> ```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a line containing a number? Do you really need to rewrite the file? Or just print out that biggest number?

Comment: Basically the way it works is that each like will contain an individual number, and then read it and output the larger number first.

Comment: what do you mean largest number first? what is after it? Can you just show a very basic example of input file and output expected?

Comment: The file contains only strings of course, but they may represent numbers (`"123`'`, `"-43.78"`). Are they all representations of integers or could they be floating point numbers?

Comment: Write a program, topN, that given a number N and an arbitrarily large file that contains individual numbers on each line (e.g. 200Gb file), will output the largest N numbers, highest first

Comment: What does "this doesn't sort the numbers correctly" mean? How would they be sorted correctly? How are they sorted incorrectly? Why is that incorrect? What ordering are you using to sort them?

Comment: Your last comment suggests your problem is a little different than what you described, in that the file is "arbitrarily" large. That suggests to me that you may need to use a procedure such as that outlined at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

```
str = File.read(in_filename)
  #=> "117\n106\n143\n147\n63\n118\n146\n93\n"
```

You could convert that string to an enumerator that enumerates lines, use [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) to sort those lines in descending order, join the resulting lines (that end in newlines) to form a string that can be written to file:

```
str.each_line.sort_by { |line| -line.to_i }.join
  #=> "147\n146\n143\n118\n117\n106\n93\n63\n"
```

Another way is to convert the string to array of integers, sort the array using [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-sort), reverse the resulting array and then join the elements of the array back into a string that can be written to file:

```
str.each_line.map(&:to_i).sort.reverse.join("\n") << "\n"
  #=> "147\n146\n143\n118\n117\n106\n93\n63\n"
```

Let's do a quick benchmark.

```
require 'benchmark/ips'

(str = 1_000_000.times.map { rand(10_000) }.join("\n") << "\n").size

Benchmark.ips do |x|
  x.report("sort_by") { str.each_line.sort_by { |line| -line.to_i }.join }
  x.report("sort")    { str.each_line.map(&:to_i).sort.reverse.join("\n") << "\n" }
  x.compare!
end

Comparison:
                sort:        0.4 i/s
             sort_by:        0.3 i/s - 1.30x  slower
```

The mighty `sort` wins again!

Comment: wow! your answer is great even with benchmarks. let me see if i can run it.

Comment: im trying to figure out how to use the benchmark on my updated code since i need to know the run time/space complexity.

Comment: You see how I've used `benchmark`. If you put your code in a method, say, `francisco`, just add a line `x.report("sort_by") { francisco(str) }`. That will not help you to determine time and space complexity, however. Those measures are obtained from an analysis of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting 200GB of data in memory will not be very performant. I would write a little helper class which only remembers the N biggest elements added so far.

```
class SortedList
  attr_reader :list

  def initialize(size)
    @list = []
    @size = size
  end

  def add(element)
    return if @min && @min > element

    list.push(element)
    reorganize_list
  end

  private

  def reorganize_list
    @list = list.sort.reverse.first(@size)
    @min = list.last
  end
end
```

Initialize an instance with the require N and the just add the values parsed from each line to this instance.

```
sorted_list = SortedList.new(n)

File.readlines("N.txt").each do |line|
  sorted_list.add(line.to_i)
end

puts sorted_list.list
```

Comment: interesting... when I provided this list... 15
7
25 
1
9
3
45
100
65

The program will only sort the first 5 even if i set N to 20 or whatever other value....

Comment: Yes, because I initialized my example `SortedList.new(5)` with `5`. Use a variable for your `N` instead: `SortedList.new(n)`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Enumerable.max](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) takes an argument which specifies how many elements will be returned, and a block which specifies how elements are compared:

```
N = 5
p File.open("test.txt").each_line.max(N){|a,b| a.to_i <=> b.to_i}
```

This does not read the entire file in memory; the file is read line by line.

Comment: thanks for your answer! will this line replace any of my original code? how can i make a running program out of this one liner?

Comment: @FranciscoCantu It is a full program now,with a `N`  variable and output to screen.

Answer (score 0):

You left this comment on your question:

"Write a program, topN, that given a number N and an arbitrarily large file that contains individual numbers on each line (e.g. 200Gb file), will output the largest N numbers, highest first."

That problem seems to me as somewhat different than the one described in the question, and also constitutes a more interesting problem. I have addressed that problem in this answer.

**Code**

```
def topN(fname, n, m=n)
  raise ArgumentError, "m cannot be smaller than n" if m < n
  f = File.open(fname)
  best = Array.new(n)
  n.times do |i|
    break best.replace(best[0,i]) if f.eof?
    best[i] = f.readline.to_i
  end
  best.sort!.reverse!
  return best if f.eof?
  new_best = Array.new(n)
  cand = Array.new(m)
  until f.eof?
    rd(f, cand)
    merge_arrays(best, new_best, cand)
  end
  f.close
  best
end
```

```
def rd(f, cand)
  cand.size.times { |i| cand[i] = (f.eof? ? -Float::INFINITY : f.readline.to_i) }
  cand.sort!.reverse!
end
```

```
def merge_arrays(best, new_best, cand)
  cand_largest = cand.first
  best_idx = best.bsearch_index { |n| cand_largest > n }
  return if best_idx.nil?
  bi = best_idx
  cand_idx = 0
  nbr_to_compare = best.size-best_idx
  nbr_to_compare.times do |i|
    if cand[cand_idx] > best[bi]
      new_best[i] = cand[cand_idx]
      cand_idx += 1
    else 
      new_best[i] = best[bi]
      bi += 1
    end
  end
  best[best_idx..-1] = new_best[0, nbr_to_compare]
end
```

**Examples**

Let's create a file with 10 million representations of integers, one per line.

```
require 'time'

FName = 'test'

(s = 10_000_000.times.with_object('') { |_,s| s << rand(100_000_000).to_s << "\n" }).size
s[0,27]
  #=> "86752031\n84524374\n29347072\n"
File.write(FName, s)
  #=> 88_888_701
```

Next, create a simple method to invoke `topN` with different arguments and to also show execution times.

```
def try_one(n, m=n)
  t = Time.now
  a = topN(FName, n, m)
  puts "#{(Time.new-t).round(2)} seconds"
  puts "top 5: #{a.first(5)}"
  puts "bot 5: #{a[n-5..n-1]}"
end
```

In testing I found that setting `m` less than `n` was never desirable in terms of computational time. Requiring that `m >= n` allowed a small simplification to the code and a small efficiency improvement. I therefore made `m >= n` a requirement.

```
try_one 100, 100
9.44 seconds
top 5: [99999993, 99999993, 99999991, 99999971, 99999964]
bot 5: [99999136, 99999127, 99999125, 99999109, 99999078]

try_one 100, 1000
9.53 seconds
top 5: [99999993, 99999993, 99999991, 99999971, 99999964]
bot 5: [99999136, 99999127, 99999125, 99999109, 99999078]

try_one 100, 10_000
9.95 seconds
top 5: [99999993, 99999993, 99999991, 99999971, 99999964]
bot 5: [99999136, 99999127, 99999125, 99999109, 99999078]
```

Here I've tested for the case of producing the `100` largest values with different number of lines of the file to read at a time `m`. As seen, the method is insensitive to this latter value. As expected, the largest 5 values and the smallest 5 values (of the 100 returned) are the same in all cases.

```
try_one 1_000
9.31 seconds
top 5: [99999993, 99999993, 99999991, 99999971, 99999964]
bot 5: [99990425, 99990423, 99990415, 99990406, 99990399]

try_one 1000, 10_000
9.24 seconds
```

The time required to return the 1,000 largest values is, in fact, slightly less than the times for returning the largest 100. I expect that's not reproducible. The top 5 are of course the same as when returning the largest 100 values. I therefore will not display that line below. The smallest 5 values of the 1000 returned are of course smaller than when the largest 100 values are returned.

```
try_one 10_000
12.15 seconds
bot 5: [99898951, 99898950, 99898946, 99898932, 99898922]

try_one 100_000
13.2 seconds
bot 5: [98995266, 98995259, 98995258, 98995254, 98995252]

try_one 1_000_000
14.34 seconds
bot 5: [89999305, 89999302, 89999301, 89999301, 89999287]
```

**Explanation**

Notice that reuse three arrays, `best`, `cand` and `new_best`. Specifically, I replace the contents of these arrays many times rather than continually creating new (potentially very large) arrays, leaving orphaned arrays to be garbage-collected. A little testing showed this approach improved performance.

We can create a small example and then step through the calculations.

```
fname = 'temp'

File.write(fname, 20.times.map { rand(100) }.join("\n") << "\n")
  #=> 58
```

This file contains representations of integers in the following array.

```
arr = File.read(fname).lines.map(&:to_i)
  #=> [9, 66, 80, 64, 67, 67, 89, 10, 62, 94, 41, 16, 0, 22, 68, 72, 41, 64, 87, 24]
```

Sorted, this is:

```
arr.sort_by! { |n| -n }
  #=> [94, 89, 87, 80, 72, 68, 67, 67, 66, 64, 64, 62, 41, 41, 24, 22, 16, 10, 9, 0]
```

Let's assume we want the 5 largest values.

```
arr[0,5]
  #=> [94, 89, 87, 80, 72]
```

First, set the two parameters: `n`, the number of largest values to return, and `m`, the number of lines to read from the file at a time.

```
n = 5
m = 5
```

The calculation follow.

```
m < n
  #=> false, so do not raise ArgumentError 
f = File.open(fname)
  #=> #<File:temp> 
best = Array.new(n)
  #=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil] 
n.times { |i| f.eof? ? (return best.replace(best[0,i])) : best[i] = f.readline.to_i }
best
  #=> [9, 66, 80, 64, 67]
best.sort!.reverse!
  #=> [80, 67, 66, 64, 9] 
f.eof?
  #=> false, so do not return 
new_best = Array.new(n)
  #=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil] 
cand = Array.new(m)
  #=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
puts "best=#{best}".rjust(52) 
until f.eof?
  rd(f, cand)
  merge_arrays(best, new_best, cand)
  puts "cand=#{cand}, best=#{best}"
end
f.close
best
  #=> [94, 89, 87, 80, 72]
```

The following is displayed.

```
                           best=[80, 67, 66, 64,  9]
cand=[94, 89, 67, 62, 10], best=[94, 89, 80, 67, 67]
cand=[68, 41, 22, 16,  0], best=[94, 89, 80, 68, 67]
cand=[87, 72, 64, 41, 24], best=[94, 89, 87, 80, 72]
```